# Localize ASP.NET Identity error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my account controller I have something like this:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
foreach (var error in result.Errors)
{
    modelstateErrors.Add(error);
}
```

Every error string is localized in English language

What's the best practice in localizing ASP.NET Identity error messages?

Are there any libraries with localized errors, and how are they implemented?

Would it be good idea to switch on every ASP.NET Identity error and return your own localized string?

Answer (score 3):

To localize ASP.Net Identity you need to install one of the following Nuget packages from the Nuget store => https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

You install the package that belong to your culture. So for **French** culture you should install **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.fr**

They all follow the pattern **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.[Culture]** where **[Culture]** is the code fo the culture.

Comment: Is there any solution if you are using a language there isn't a nuget package for?

Comment: You can override IdentityErrorDescriber class and provide messages from localized resource files. Check this article for details: http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/20-Localizing_Identity_Error_Messages

Answer (score 2):

Create e base controller and extend every controller from it

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{                
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // verify which kind of exception it is and do somethig like logging
    }

}
```

It is one of the best practice por handlling errors, but for the localizing itself do what @codeNotFound said.